# How can I display a string entered by the user vertically as many times as there are characters in the string

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class VerticalPrinting
{

     htmlWriter( );
}

   Public static void main htmlWriter( )
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print(“enter a string”);
        String s1 = scan.nextLine( );

         Int n = s1.length( ) - 1;

          Char c = ‘ ‘;

             For ( int j = 0; j <= n ; j++)
             {
               C= s1.charAt(j);
                System.out.println(c+” “);
             }


     }

}
```

Comment: You should add an example of your user input, and what you'd like the output to be.

Comment: `Public static void main htmlWriter` is just wrong.

Comment: so is `For` - you have to follow the correct syntax for java.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: There's a lot more than that (`Int`, `Char`, `C=`); but some browser's (particularly my phone) make it very difficult to convince _not_ to do that.